# How to avoid loading all children of a parent record in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Working from a .Net Core Web API application that uses EF Core 2.1, I am trying to prevent loading all of a parent's children record when using an include.

Here's the set up:
The API is pulling an IEnumerable collection of Customers.  I have an Include statement to pull the CustomerType which is coming from a separate table.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomer()
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customerList = _context.Customer
        .Include(i => i.CustomerType);
    return customerList;
}
```

When the IEnumerable collection is returned, each Customer contains the CustomerType object which then also includes a Customer collection of all customers with that CustomerType.  As you can imagine, this is creating a huge data set.

How do I prevent EF Core from including the Customer collection of the CustomerType?  I tried turning off lazy loading with

```
_context.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

but that had no effect.

Comment: I think Projection (Select) can help you in this case

Comment: why not carefully read the documention on lazy loading. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Comment: Thanks, JRB.  Per the documentation, "EF Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties."  Based on continued research, it is my understanding that what I'm see is by design and cannot be "turned off."

Answer (score 0):

Based on vivek's response, I've successfully updated the API as such:

```
[HttpGet]
public object GetCustomer()
{
    var customerList = _context.Customer
        .Select(s => new 
        {
            s,
            s.CustomerType.CustomerType
        });
    return customerList;
}
```